# Firebase onAuthStateChanged() keep refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have the following JavaScript code and the page just keep refreshing. It is just how it sounds like, I have my console open in order to see which `console.log()` is used. I see `Not logged` and then it refreshes the page then again displays `Not logged` and refreshes and goes in a loop.  I read that `onAuthStateChanged()` is called when a state change occurs and until a page is completely refreshed the state changes a couple of times.

How should I proceed in case I just want to redirect user in case he is not logged in?

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  let everyHeaderUsername = document.getElementsByClassName("user-header-username");
  if (user) {
    console.log("Logged");
    for (let i = 0; i < everyHeaderUsername.length; i++) {
      everyHeaderUsername[i].textContent = `${user.displayName}`;
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Not Logged");
    for (let i = 0; i < everyHeaderUsername.length; i++) {
      everyHeaderUsername[i].textContent = "Sign in";
    }
    console.log("Not logged in");
    window.location.href = "index.html";
  }
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the page just keeps refreshing".

Answer (score 1):

I think In your else condition. You are doing:

```
    window.location.href = "index.html";
```

So when the page is initially loaded. The state onAuthStateChanged runs and user is not found so the page gets updated. And the cycle repeats.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with keep refreshing? And yes, onAuthStateChanged() is called after an authentication state change.

But for simplicity I would go with the following code:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```